# How to display images when using for loop in IJulia?

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

i want to display images in Jupyter using `Image.jl`.
the [doc](https://github.com/timholy/Images.jl/blob/master/doc/index.md#image-viewing) says:

> If you're using the IJulia notebook, images will be displayed automatically.
>
> Julia code for the display of images can be found in ImageView. Installation of this package is recommended but not required.

but i failed to find any way to automatically display images in a for loop. the code below is an example:

```
using Images

for i=1:10
    convert(Image,rand(100,100))
end
```

i guess there exits an undocumented function to draw images in IJulia which can be called explicitly to show out those hidden results. thanks in advance! @tholy

Comment: The jupyter/IJulia notebooks will display the _only_ the latest "lone variable line"/variable assigment. A [discussion on displaying latest variable assigment](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/93#issuecomment-141194296) brought up an extension to force display of a variable anywhere in the cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `display` function, which is what IJulia uses, you can find it's documentation in the [*Multimedia I/O*](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/io-network/#multimedia-i-o) section of the Julia manual.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply @ismael BTW, i suddenly found that this is also implicitly documented in `IJulia`'s [README](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl#clearing-output) which aims at telling users how to use `display(...)` and `IJulia.clear_output(true)` to make animation frames.

Comment: @GnimucKey you are welcome! If my answer solved your question, please mark it as the rigth answer. I didn't know about `IJulia.clear_output(true)`!